# Issue with React Native Share with passing the object

Tags: react-native, share

I tried to use **Share** from 'react-native', and want to pass *shop object* to display the message using its attribute. However, when running the application, it is undefined. Could you help me with this issue?

```
import { StyleSheet, View, Image, Button, FlatList, Dimensions, SafeAreaView, ScrollView, Share } from 'react-native';

...

    const [shop, setShop] = useState(
        {
            id: 1,
            eventName: "Wild Rose Special Offer",
            eventDesc: "25% off! vs Regular price",
            name: "Oak & Vine",
            desc: "This is amazing opportunity!",
            location: "1026 16 Ave NW, Calgary",
            image: "https://i.imgur.com/UPrs1EWl.jpg",
            dueDate: "2020-04-30",
            officeHour: "11:00 ~ 20:30 (Mon~Sun)",
            call: "(587) 438-0275"
        }
    );

    const onShare = async ({ shop },) => {
        try {
            const result = await Share.share({
                message:
                    `[${shop.eventName}] at ${shop.name} by ${shop.dueDate}`,
            });
            if (result.action === Share.sharedAction) {
                if (result.activityType) {
                    // shared with activity type of result.activityType
                } else {
                    // shared
                }
            } else if (result.action === Share.dismissedAction) {
                // dismissed
            }
        } catch (error) {
            alert(error.message);
        }
    };
...
```

Comment: what is undefined?

Comment: @DevLover Thank you for your comment. Every attributes mentioned in the message '`[${shop.eventName}] at ${shop.name} by ${shop.dueDate}`'